# Mongoimport strict JSON {$date:XXX} as ISODate

Tags: regex, mongodb, sed

I have a couple of GB's exported from an RDBMS as JSON. All dates are formatted in the Strict JSON format, i.e. `{$date:1354810746067}`.

Mongoimport does not seem to convert it into the desired ISODate. It only works if it's formatted as `Date(1354810746067)`.

Is there an option to tweak mongoimport to accept {$date:..} as ISODate?

Or should I pass my import through some `sed` script, maybe?

Sample input would be like

```
{cleared:true,category:"general auditing",transactionId:null,details:{new_terminal_mode:"test value-24",company_old_id:2534,new_terminal_state:"test value-28",reduction_type:"test value-3",transition_times:[{$date:1355408317000},{$date:1355407983000},{$date:1355413490000},{$date:1355411339000},{$date:1355414485000},{$date:1355414378000},{$date:1355408061000},{$date:1355408064000}]},_id:"69",dateTime:{$date:1354813457327},severity:20,eventType:"log_event_count_threshold_reached",systemId:693972591865925,carParkId:0}
```

I tried with

```
cat file | sed -e s/{$date:\([0-9]*\)}/Date\(\1\)/g | mongoimport -c test
```

But my regex skills failed there :-(.

Comment: In which format do you have date in your previous RDBMS. Is it Unix time, but isn't UNIX time 10 or so character long.

Comment: It's milliseconds since epoch, which matches the requirements of MongoDB dates http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON.
Unix time is seconds since epoch, so you'd need to multiply x1000 for MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't now mongoimport so i can't help you here.

But for the sed, try with some quotes in your sed :

```
sed -e 's/{$date:\([0-9]*\)}/Date\(\1\)/g' file
```

PS: your regex is good.

Comment: My regex worked in notepad++, but not in sed. But indeed, I was just missing the qoutes...

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes, the other is not a valid JSON: {"$date":1354810746067}